# How do I become Stormy Eyed?

Tags: fallen-london

I've come across numerous interesting Storylet choices, many in dreams, that require the Quality "Stormy-Eyed":

[image: example]

I haven't, as of yet, been able to find out how you gain this quality. **How do I become Stormy Eyed?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Stormy-Eyed* is a quality gained after completing the final chain of the What The Thunder Said storylets. Once you have at least 1 of it, you can increase it via storylets earlier in the chain, and from storylets in the Mirror-Marches and Mutton Island. You can also lose it via a storylet in A State of Some Confusion. As you can see, it is a way of repeating the existing What The Thunder Said chain in a new way.